# Regex to get text within text and ignore text with the format <xxx>

Tags: regex, tags

Imagine I have the following text: This is a text

If I only want to get "This is a text", then the regular expression will be:

```
(?<=\<tag\>).*(?=\<\/tag\>)
```

Imagine now that the text is something like:

```
<tag> <Arial>This is a text<Arial></tag>
```

What would be now the regular expression that gets "This is a text" and ignores everything else? 
The word Arial may not be fixed and varies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `(?<=>)(?!\s+<)[^<>]*(?=<)`, but in real life, you'd rather use a HTML/XML parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks, but in that expression I need somewhy to identify <tag>

Answer (score 0):

It depends to the regex flavour. If your regexps allows [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), you can go with:

```
\<(\w+)\>([^<>]*)\<\/\1\>
```

and `\1` will refer to the content of `(\w+)`.

In this case, the text "This is a text" will be matched by group 2 (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cEDXcL/1)).

Notice that in most of flavors you cannot use the `+` inside lookbekind.

Otherwise, you have to be more broad and use something like:

```
(?<=\>)[^<>]*(?=\<)
```

In any case, probably the best solution is to use a DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I really have to detect the <tag> which is outermost, and ignore the inner tag <Arial>.

Comment: If you want to force the presence of the tag "<tag>" , just wrap the above regex with lookaround (something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/0uVz1Q/1))

Comment: no match in your example. And that example really looks extremely complex :( I really need to force the existence of "<tag>"...

Comment: I updated it. It is complex because this is not a job for regular expressions.